# Como abrir uma conexão via socket?

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma aplicação em `PHP`/`Javascript` (utilizando o framework `jQuery`), quero abrir uma conexão via `socket` para um sistema de chat, parecido com o G-talk do Google, porém não estou conseguindo abrir `socket` de jeito nenhum.

Não posso usar nenhuma solução baseada no `node.js`.

Tentei o seguinte:

**CLIENT**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            WebSocketTest()
            function WebSocketTest(){   
                // Let us open a web socket
                var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/index.php");

                ws.onopen = function(){
                    // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                    ws.send("Message to send");
                    alert("Message is sent...");
                };

                ws.onmessage = function (evt)   { 
                    var received_msg = evt.data;
                    alert("Message is received...");
                };

                ws.onclose = function(){ 
                    // websocket is closed.
                    alert("Connection is closed..."); 
                };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        [...]
    </body>
</html>
```

**SERVER**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

    /* Get the port for the WWW service. */
    $service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

    /* Get the IP address for the target host. */
    $address = gethostbyname('localhost');

    /* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if ($socket === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "OK.\n";
    }

    echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
    $result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
    } else {
        echo "OK.\n";
    }

    $in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $in .= "Host: localhost\r\n";
    $in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    $out = '';

    echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
    socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
    echo "OK.\n";

    echo "Reading response:\n\n";
    while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
        echo $out;
    }

    echo "Closing socket...";
    socket_close($socket);
    echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

Porém, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> ebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/chat_4/index.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

Você teria uma solução mais prática para verificar quando uma mensagem foi inserida no banco de forma dinâmica?

Answer (score 4):

Bom dia, não sei se vc já obteve sua solução, mas posso ajudar com uma solução que funciona em alguns de meus sistemas.

Lado do servidor
**server.php**

```
<?php
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9000';
$null = NULL;
```

acima vc define seu host, porta de conexão e a variável com valor nulo.
Obs. Importante vc definir o host com o endereço de seu servidor (IP).

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, 0, $port);
socket_listen($socket);
$clients = array($socket);


while (true) {
    $changed = $clients;
    socket_select($changed, $null, $null, 0, 10);

if (in_array($socket, $changed)) {
    $socket_new = socket_accept($socket);
    $clients[] = $socket_new;

    $header = socket_read($socket_new, 1024);
    perform_handshaking($header, $socket_new, $host, $port);

    socket_getpeername($socket_new, $ip);
    $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' connected')));
    send_message($response);

    $found_socket = array_search($socket, $changed);
    unset($changed[$found_socket]);
}
```

nesse momento 'abaixo' eu inicio a criação de um array que será convertido em json. Esses dados serão os que serão lançados no túnel do socket, ou seja, a comunição entre seu servidor e client será feito por esse json.

Obs. esses valores podem ser definidas conforme sua necessidade e utilidade.

```
foreach ($changed as $changed_socket) { 


    while(socket_recv($changed_socket, $buf, 1024, 0) >= 1)
    {
        $received_text = unmask($buf); //unmask data
        $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text);

        $user_id_cliente = $tst_msg->id_cliente;
        $empresa_id = $tst_msg->empresa_id;
        $user_time_mensagem = $tst_msg->time_mensagem;
        $user_conteudo_mensagem = $tst_msg->conteudo_mensagem;
        $user_nome_cliente = $tst_msg->nome_cliente;
        $quem_esta_enviado = $tst_msg->quem_envia;
        $produto_detalhes = $tst_msg->produto_detalhes;
        $grupo_men = $tst_msg->grupo_mensagem;
        $nome_empresa = $tst_msg->nome_empresa;

        $regra_empresa = $tst_msg->regra_empresa;
        $atacado_empresa = $tst_msg->atacado_empresa;
        $min_empresa = $tst_msg->min_empresa;
        $cidade_cliente = $tst_msg->cidade_cliente;
        $valor_pedido = $tst_msg->valor_pedido;
        $pedido_mandar = $tst_msg->pedido_mandar;

        $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('nome_empresa'=>$nome_empresa,'grupo_mensagem'=>$grupo_men,'pedido_mandar'=>$pedido_mandar,'regra_empresa'=>$regra_empresa,'atacado_empresa'=>$atacado_empresa,'min_empresa'=>$min_empresa,'cidade_cliente'=>$cidade_cliente,'valor_pedido'=>$valor_pedido,'produto_detalhes'=>$produto_detalhes,'quem_envia'=>$quem_esta_enviado,'empresa_id'=>$empresa_id,'id_cliente'=>$user_id_cliente, 'time_mensagem'=>$user_time_mensagem, 'conteudo_mensagem'=>$user_conteudo_mensagem, 'nome_cliente'=>$user_nome_cliente)));
        send_message($response_text); //send data
        break 2; //exist this loop
    }
```

continuando...

```
    $buf = @socket_read($changed_socket, 1024, PHP_NORMAL_READ);
    if ($buf === false) { 
        $found_socket = array_search($changed_socket, $clients);
        socket_getpeername($changed_socket, $ip);
        unset($clients[$found_socket]);

        $response = mask(json_encode(array('type'=>'system', 'message'=>$ip.' disconnected')));
        send_message($response);
    }
}
}

socket_close($socket);

function send_message($msg)
{
    global $clients;
    foreach($clients as $changed_socket)
    {
        @socket_write($changed_socket,$msg,strlen($msg));
    }
    return true;
}


function unmask($text) {
    $length = ord($text[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {
        $masks = substr($text, 4, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 8);
    }
    elseif($length == 127) {
        $masks = substr($text, 10, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 14);
    }
    else {
        $masks = substr($text, 2, 4);
        $data = substr($text, 6);
    }
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
        $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    return $text;
}

function mask($text)
{
    $b1 = 0x80 | (0x1 & 0x0f);
    $length = strlen($text);

    if($length <= 125)
        $header = pack('CC', $b1, $length);
    elseif($length > 125 && $length < 65536)
        $header = pack('CCn', $b1, 126, $length);
    elseif($length >= 65536)
        $header = pack('CCNN', $b1, 127, $length);
    return $header.$text;
}

function perform_handshaking($receved_header,$client_conn, $host, $port)
{
    $headers = array();
    $lines = preg_split("/\r\n/", $receved_header);
    foreach($lines as $line)
    {
        $line = chop($line);
        if(preg_match('/\A(\S+): (.*)\z/', $line, $matches))
        {
            $headers[$matches[1]] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    $secKey = $headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key'];
    $secAccept = base64_encode(pack('H*', sha1($secKey . '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11')));

    $upgrade  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\n" .
    "Upgrade: websocket\r\n" .
    "Connection: Upgrade\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Origin: $host\r\n" .
    "WebSocket-Location: ws://$host:$port/demo/shout.php\r\n".
    "Sec-WebSocket-Accept:$secAccept\r\n\r\n";
    socket_write($client_conn,$upgrade,strlen($upgrade));
}
```

Lado do Cliente **seu-arquivo.js**

lembra do host e da porta? são inseridos abaixo

```
var wsUrir = "ws://127.0.0.1:9000";
    connection = new WebSocket(wsUrir);
```

conexão aberto, ativa o bloco abaixo

```
    connection.onopen = function(ev) { 
        console.log('socket aberto');
    };
```

as transações, mensagens, requisições, etc, rodam abaixo.

```
    connection.onmessage = function(ev) {
        var msg_ws = JSON.parse(ev.data);

        var type_ws = msg_ws.type;
        var ws_id_cliente = msg_ws.id_cliente;

        console.log(ev.data);

        if(type_ws !== 'system'){

            // suas condições aqui

        }


    };
```

caso ocorra algum erro durante ou após a conexão a função abaixo é acionada.

```
    connection.onerror  = function(ev){
        console.log("Error Occurred - "+ev.data);
    };
```

se acaso a conexão encerrar, abaixo é acionado

```
    connection.onclose  = function(ev){
        console.log("conexao fechada"); 
    };
```

Após configurar seus arquivos vc terá que acessar seu terminal, navegar até o diretório que encontra-se o arquivo **server.php** e digitar o comando:

```
php -q **server.php**
```

Obs. certifique-se de ter o php instalado e que a variável **php** seja global em seu SO.

Outra observação importante é que o servidor socket só funciona no php com essa chamada em linha de comando, ou seja, caso vc tente acessar por url direto no navegador o arquivo não executará e caso feche a conexão também será encerrada.

Enfim, caso tenha alguma dúvida me contacte, o que eu souber eu compartilho. Abraços!

Comment: Acabei fazendo um sistema em ajax que fica verificando se existe uma nova mensagem no banco. Do ponto de vista do desempenho é uma tragédia. Vou tentar aplicar a sua a solução. Obrigado.

Comment: Rapaz, como você disse, é literalmente uma tragédia, eu tive essa mesma idéia q você no início do meu projeto e sofri muito até conhecer o socket, veja, esse código funciona muito bem pra mim tenho certeza que funcionará pra você também, se tiver dúvidas não hesite em me perguntar.

Comment: @LuizAugustoNeto como seria o código do lado cliente para enviar as mensagens para o servidor?